# Python: how to keep a loop running in background when other function is being performed

Tags: python

I'm trying to control a robot based on real-time sensor data. I built a loop that receive the real-time sensor samples and calculate the difference with the former one when the loop receive a new sample. And if the difference is higher than a threshold value, a function is called to have the robot move for 2 sec.

My problem is, now during the robot is moving, the whole loop is suspended (Robot control API method `.wait_for_completed()` is called), and when the loop is restarted, the sensor data sample revived is not the real-time data but the data generated during the robot is moving. What I want is to keep the main loop running when the robot is moving, so that the robot can always use the real-time data to judge whether to move, or just discard the data during the robot is running.

the pseudo code is like

```
def move():
    robot.move().wait_for_completed() # usually takes 2 seconds

sample = 0
lastsample = 0

def main():
    while True:
         sample = sensor.message() # the sample is a float number
         diff = sample - lastsample
         lastsample = sample
         if diff > 300:
              move()

main()
```

I'm searching for asyncio and multi-process. But I am not sure I am in the right direction.
I'm not sure whether I describe my question clearly, if not, please ask.

Comment: I suggest you start a thread. `t = threading.Thread(target=function_to_run,daemon=True)` and `t.start()`. The loop would be in the function_to_run and after starting the thread you call move. daemon=True makes the thread exit when the move() is finished so that the program can terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're in the right direction, but I think it's better to use an asyncio library rather than multi-process one.

You can use greenlet/tornado or any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Must import the thread module in your code, then you have to be passed into a variable and defined

```
import thread as th
```